# Pass text field value to url parameter within the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

We are trying to register users to a webinar and the only way to do it is via a one-click registration link that is normally used on an email. But we need to use this link on an optin form as well.

https://register.webinar.com/auto-register?webid=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=1

We have three schedules to choose from and this is set on the parameter 'schedule=X'

I'm using radio button with onclick action so that the submit link will changed based on the schedule chosen. e.g.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="submit.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <label for="FirstName">First Name *</label>
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" />
    <label for="Email">Email *</label>
    <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" />
    <div class="radio_form">
            <input name="sel_schedule" type="radio" value="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=1" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('next_url').href=this.value;" checked="checked">
            <label>Schedule 1</label>

            <input name="sel_schedule" type="radio" value="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=2" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('next_url').href=this.value;">
            <label>Schedule 2</label>

            <input name="sel_schedule" type="radio" value="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=3" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('next_url').href=this.value;">
            <label>Schedule 3</label>
    </div>
<div class="submit_form">
    <a id="next_url" name="next_url" href="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=1" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Submit</a>
```

Now the other issue, how can I pass the field values for the name and email on the registration link before they click on the submit button? I thought of using onchange for the text fields but I don't know how to pass the info in the url parameter of the registration link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"via a one-click registration link"* - How is it a one-click registration if the user also has to enter their name and email *and* press a submit button?

Comment: actually this link is for an email click. so those field are populated on the email. this is the only registration link we can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can access url parameters and use those to populate form fields like this -

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="submit.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
<label for="FirstName">First Name *</label>
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" />
<label for="Email">Email *</label>
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" />
<div class="radio_form">
        <input name="sel_schedule" type="radio" value="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=1" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('next_url').href=this.value;" checked="checked">
        <label>Schedule 1</label>

        <input name="sel_schedule" type="radio" value="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=2" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('next_url').href=this.value;">
        <label>Schedule 2</label>

        <input name="sel_schedule" type="radio" value="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=3" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('next_url').href=this.value;">
        <label>Schedule 3</label>
</div>
<div class="submit_form">
    <a id="next_url" name="next_url" href="https://app.webinarjam.net/ew/auto-register?webicode=69bb17b947&memberid=39867&firstname=yourname&email=your@email.com&schedule=1" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Submit</a>
</div>
    </form>

    <script>
    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    };

    var webid = getUrlParameter('webid');
    var firstName = getUrlParameter('firstname');
    var email = getUrlParameter('email');
    var schedule = getUrlParameter('schedule');

    document.getElementById("FirstName").value = firstName;
    document.getElementById("Email").value = email;
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks T.Shah but what we need to do is the other way around. Pass the data on the form fields (name and email) to the final link on the 'a' button. so when they click the link their name and email will be there.

Comment: Then instead of 'POST' method, use 'GET' method for the form and it would be done...